# is it possible to receive notification on MS Teams about pass or failure of the AWS pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, webhooks, microsoft-teams, aws-devops

can I be notified on ms-teams whenever developers push to CodeCommit, but the notifications must be alerting the outcome of the pipeline if it fails or passed since it's sourcing from CodeCommit?
I tried to use the webhook but the problem is I don't know where or how to integrate the webhook link to the AWS pipeline, It was easy the time we were using slack but now its ms-teams

Comment: You can create a Incoming Webhook and configure it in your pipeline. Please refer below doc: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/send-notification-on-a-microsoft-teams-channel-from-a-data/ba-p/2456636